# combine and merge array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

while merging array i got many isseus.
i used array_merge and array_combine in laravl but no success

```
array:4 [▼
  "resident_id" => array:19 [▼
    2 => "2"
    1841 => "1841"
    
  ]
  "community_id" => array:19 [▼
    2 => "25"
    1841 => "25"
    1843 => "25"
    
  ]
  "out_of_community" => array:5 [▼
    2 => 
      "2020-09-25"
                                      
    
    1841 =>
      "2020-09-25"
                                      
      "
  ]



 i want 

  resident_id   community_id  out_of_community
    2             25            2020-09-25
    1841           25            2020-09-25
```

please help me to solve it.

i did

$arr = $request->all();
$a = array_merge($arr);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if array_merge is the way to go. Looks like you are trying to transpose the data in a tabular format identified by the keys/ids in each of the sub arrays. Here is one approach that might work for you:

```
$keyCodes = array_keys($array['resident_id']); //get the keys to use when constructing the transposed array. $array is your data array
$dataToTabularFormat = [];
collect($keyCodes)->each(function($keyCode) use (&$dataToTabularFormat, $array) {
    collect($array)->each(
        function($item, $key) use($keyCode, &$dataToTabularFormat ) {
            $dataToTabularFormat[$keyCode][$key] = $item[$keyCode] ;
        }
    );    
});
```

Now, you can use `$dataToTabularFormat` to populate the table. In your blade view, you can do something like this:

```
@foreach($dataToTabularFormat as $item)
 {{ $item['resident_id' }} {{ $item['community_id' }} {{ $item['out_of_community']}}
@endforeach
```